# Control flow of the try...catch...finally control structure

Tags: control-flow, try-catch-finally

I have a `try`...`catch`...`finally` block whose `catch` rethrows the exception:

```
try
{
    startBombCountdownAndRunAsFastAsYouCan();
}
catch (BombExplodedOnYourFaceException ex)
{
    displayMessage("Hahaha! It blew up on your face!");
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    cleanFloor();
}

displayMessage("Wow, you pulled it off!");
```

In this example, I need that `cleanFloor()` be executed regardless of whether the exception was thrown or not. So the question is: Is the `finally` clause *always* executed, regardless of whether the exception is rethrown in the corresponding `catch` clause?

Comment: What language is this in?  There may be subtle differences between the behaviour in different languages.

Comment: No language in particular. In my actual program, I am using C#. (And I am hating every minute of it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the exact purpose that the finally concept was created.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the finally block will always be executed.

Also, as a side note if you're not going to use the explicitly caught exception, you should just use "catch { ... throw; }.

For reference:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The `finally` is *usually* executed, but not *always*.

Consider the following Java program, where the `finally` block is not executed:

```
package test;
public class TestFinally {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new Exception ("throw!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("catch!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("finally!");
        }       
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
catch!
```

The finally catch will only be executed if control is ever returned to the `catch`, which as we can see is never guaranteed; determining if you execute the `finally` is basically reduced to the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

In practice, the `finally` block will *usually* be executed.  Not *always*.

---

Peter Norvig's [Java IAQ: Infrequently Answered Questions](http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html) has a bit on this:

> #### Q: The code in a finally clause will never fail to execute, right?
>
> Well, hardly ever. But here's an example where the finally code will not execute, regardless of the value of the boolean choice:
>
> ```
> try {
>     if (choice) {
>         while (true) ;
>     } else {
>         System.exit(1);
>     }
> } finally {
>     code.to.cleanup();
> }
> ```

Comment: I was assuming in my question that the control flow would exit the `try` part of the `try`...`catch`...`finally` construct. And I was also assuming my program would not abnormally terminate.